# How to do optional group at regex ? php python

Tags: php, python, regex

I want to get the amazon asin from amazon link :

amazon link examples :

```
https://www.amazon.com/Sonix-Case-Samsung-Galaxy-Edge/dp/B00VWKSM52
https://www.amazon.com/Sonix-Case-Samsung-Galaxy-Edge/dp/B00VWKSM52?ref ...
https://www.amazon.com/Sonix-Case-Samsung-Galaxy-Edge/dp/B00VWKSM52/ref...
```

so here what I am doing :

```
<\/(?:dp|gp\/product)\/(.*?)(?:\/|%3|\?)?>
```

I have set `?` at the end to indicate that `(?:\/|%3|\?)` is optional , however it doesn't work, why?

Comment: Get group1 value to capture the 10 character ASIN: `\/(?:dp|gp\/product)\/(\w{10})`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/HSUDaI/1)

Comment: Thank you , but what the optional doesn't work the way I wrote !

Comment: The regex in the post looks for `/` followed by `dp` or `gp/product` followed by `/` followed by any number of characters (lazily) followed by a `/` or `%3` or `?` optionally. Since the `.*?` is lazy, and `(?:\/|%3|\?)?` the match will be immediately after the last `/`. See [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/HSUDaI/2)

Answer (score 0):

The less than and greater than symbols should not be present.

```
\/(?:dp|gp\/product)\/(.*?)(?:\/|%3|\?)?
```

https://regex101.com/r/ImAmhf/1/

Answer (score 0):

Engine rules go in this priority:

- Match left to right.
- Stop immediately when a match is found.
- Quantifiers `+*?` will match if possible (greedy).
- ***Qualified*** quantifiers `?` will *not* match if possible.

Form:  Construct - quantifier - ***qualifier***
Example: `A` `*` `?`

In your regex, `.*?` tells the engine
optionally match anything, but prefer *NOT* to match anything (non-greedy).

Since you have an *optional* construct after this, the regex engine *STOPS*
immediately, and never matches after this clause.

To work around this, redesign the regex so the last clause is required,
but wrap it into a optional cluster:

```
 /
 (?: dp | gp/product )
 /
 (?:
      ( .*? )                       # (1)
      (?:
           /
        |  %3
        |  \? 
      )
 )?
```